# MS Access/ODBC converts SQL Server decimal field to small text

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2016

If I add a SQL Server view as a linked table in MS Access (2016) via ODBC (2018.183.0101), one specific field is added as short text instead of a `Decimal(18,4)` which it really is.

If I add the source SQL table in which that field is resided, it is shown properly as `Decimal(18,4)`.

From memory I think that Access determines the data type based on a scan of the first 1000 fields, but I cannot find anything about that anymore.

Can anyone explain this issue?

[image: Table design view with field of concern]

Below is the SQL from the view:

```
ALTER VIEW [sgo].[cdbArticles]

AS

SELECT [ID], [Contract_nr], <left some company specific info out here>[!
        , GainShare, GainShareRemark

FROM DataFactory.cdb.ContractItems

GO
```

Comment: A view should show the same data type as the base table unless you perform a calculation on it. Maybe show the view definituon

Comment: Are you *sure* the column within the `VIEW` *is* a `decimal(18,4)`. In truth, it sounds like it isn't. Perhaps you're doing formatting in the `VIEW` or something. For example `FORMAT(SomeDecimal,'#,0.00')` does **not** return a `decimal` (it returns an `nvarchar(4000)`). We can't see the `VIEW`'s definition, so difficult to comment further.

Comment: Hi both, I added the view, but there is no formatting or conversion in it whatsoever.

Comment: No, Access determines the data type from the info it gets from the ODBC driver. This usually works for views as well as for tables. (Except it can't determine the PK for views.) -- If you create a minimal view with just `ID` and `GainShare`, and link that view, does the same happen?

Comment: maybe you switched some columns around between view and real table and hasn't refreshed access?

Comment: @Andre: If I create the view you described and then the field is added as decimal field.

Comment: @siggemannen I deleted the table and added it back again just to be sure, but the issue remains.

Comment: Which driver are you using, exactly? The ODBC version tells us little about the supported functionality

Comment: @ErikA: ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server (64-bit)

Comment: *and then the field is added as decimal field* -- so apparently the column itself is not the issue. It's either other columns (try adding them one-by-one), or "something went wrong" with the original view. DROP and CREATE it from scratch in SQL Server, and do the same in Access (delete link, then link as you would with a new view).

Comment: You could use Money as the data type. Has four decimals as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok somehow altering the view with exactly the same SQL somehow seems to fix it.
I did not delete the view, just alter it. After that a simple 'refresh link' on Access side updates the data type for the column to number.

Maybe, it somehow stores/remembers the datatypes each time you adjust the view. But that is just speculation.